# trigger('create') renders properly in Chrome but not in Android emulator

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to add  an input field dynamically. When I test the code, it works in chrome browser but when testing in Android emulator which is wrapped with cordova, it is not working. Why it is so ? I even tried two more examples and all results the same.

```
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <h3>Add List</h3>
        <form>
            <div data-role="controlgroup"  id="addwhat">
                <input type="text" name="inp0" class="inp" />
            </div>
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="verrical" class="aisubmit">
                <input type="submit" data-theme="b" id="addinput" value="Add Input"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
<script>
    var ct =0;
    $('body').on('click', "#addinput", function (e) {
        ct++;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#addwhat').append('<input type="text" name="list' + ct + '"/>');
        $('#thelists').trigger('create');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The controlgroup widget creates a container DIV that child controls should be added to:  http://api.jquerymobile.com/controlgroup/#method-container

Also, in jQM 1.4.x you can call enhanceWithin() instead of trigger("create").

See if this code change helps:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){        
    var ct =0;
    $(document).on('click', "#addinput", function (e) {
        ct++;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();        
        $('#addwhat').controlgroup( "container" ).append('<input type="text" name="list' + ct + '"/>').enhanceWithin();
    });    
});
```